# Explain "There can be many keys (and their associated values) in each partition, but the records for any given key are all in a single partition"

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

"There can be many keys (and their associated values) in each partition, but the records for any given key are all in a single partition." This is a line of a famous hadoop text book. I am not getting the entire meaning of the second part of it which says "but the records for any given key are all in a single partition." Is this mean that all the records for a single key should be in a single partition or something else.

Comment: This is a general computer question and it would be better on [superuser](http://superuser.com) As stack overflow is just for programming questions.

Comment: Yes, it means that all records with the same partitioning key must be in one partition (i.e. not span multiple partitions)

Answer (score 1):

> but the records for any given key are all in a single partition

If you have one key, the key and its associated value, must be on a single partition. Sometimes the value can be rather large. But this is a constraint on the size of a value. It must be small enough to fit on a single partition.

Note, there maybe other constants on both keys and values, depending on what you use for back-end storage, for example, a single key-value pair may be required to fit into the node's memory.